# Fragment not attached to my activity

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-fragments, fragment, illegalstateexception, android-fragmentactivity

First of all I am using support library (android-support-v4.jar) for using fragments.

I have an activity with layout containing a fragment in it. So when the activity starts it calls onCreateView method of my fragment. In this method I inflated a layout( containing a linearlayout and a listview in it ) and return that inflated view.

So when the activity starts it loads my listview and call a webservice and in response of the webservice loads the data on the listview.

Every thing works perfect as expected. **But the problem is** when I press the back button and restart the activity then it doesn't attach my fragment to the activity and throws IllegalStateException when I try to call getActivity(). And also throws NullPointerException when I try to call getView() method of my fragment.

One more thing to mention that when i see the view hierarchy from the TraceView tool then it shows my fragment views there.

Please help me!

Comment: any luck after this time? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: I have posted the answer below. May be it can help you

Comment: Does that help you to fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and hence solved it as well.
I was using the Observer interface to get the response from the web service. So when i started the activity first time then I added(or registered) my fragment activity to the Observable class and received the response but forgot to remove(or de-register) my fragment object when it destroyed. So when the activity and fragment restarts it again add my fragment object to the Observable class so now Observable class now has two instances of fragment first one has been destroyed and the current fragment and web service is called and it first respond with the destroyed fragment and that time it will crash. So i removed the fragment instance from the Observable class in the onDestroy method of fragment and it working now.

So the problem is not with the fragments but with the multiple instances of my fragment.

Comment: how u diagnose that two instance of same fragmetn i m getting same error in case of viewpager + fragmetn

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening in your case so that I could understand the situation better.

Comment: i have mainactivity that has so many fragmetns ---> out of which  one fragment  (profileFragment )  contains viewpager + designtablayout --->and its viewpager adapter have been iniitialized from fragmetnts ---->Profilefragment contains button on click of button i m repalcing fragment from this code http://pastie.org/10361207  moreover the new fragment contains back key .....> i click on back key and i just pop up the stack  from the fragmetns

Comment: now i came to the same ProfileFragment but issue is -----> this time  my app should show same tab selected that was at the time of pressing button .....> so once i tried to change page then my app crash saying that my fragment is not attched to any activity ?

Comment: I think you need to initialize your pager adapter again as when you replaced your ProfileFragment from EditUserProfileFragment then it will destroy the existing ProfileFragment. So when you pressed back button then it gets recreated and you have to initialize your pager adapter again here.

Comment: any idea how to use this  lib with passed arraylist https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders/StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter.java  for both as sections and for section content

Comment: I found this code incomplete because it does not show the logic how this class is differentiating that which is a header or which is an item. Apart from that, You have to arrange your arraylist in the same order as you want it to be displayed. Your arraylist will contains data for both headers and items. You will pass your arraylist with header and item layout ids to this class constructor and set it to your listview. Thats it.

Comment: this library contains code for which one is header and which one is item i have two arraylists..... one contains sectionHeading another contains arraylist f objects contains two arrays one for privateList[] , another for publicList[] but i m not getting how will i render it ?

Comment: According to the code you sent me using only one arraylist which contains both headers and items. 
And one more thing, I think you should ask this as a separate question because your question is not related to this page.